# How can I slice out a specific chunk of a (partially) downloaded file based on a hex signature?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hex, buffer, binary-data

**What I'm attempting to solve:**

There is an **uncompressed** zip file which contains two (2) separate files within it. One is a manifest which contains certain metadata about the zip, and the other is an encrypted payload.

I need to download ONLY the manifest file portion of the zip package.

**Here's my plan:**

1. Download the last 5kb of the entire zip package in order to capture the portion of the zip which contains the **central directory** for the zip file. In this central directory data exists which list the files contained in the zip, and their byte locations. I download the last 5kb by doing a normal GET with the `Range` header set to: `-5000`. This works wonderfully.
2. Using the 5kb of data I downloaded in the previous step, I search for the start of **central directory** using it's unique hex signature as outlined in the [Zip spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#File_headers). The hex signature is `0x02014b50`, if you're curious.
3. Parse the central directory and find the manifest file's byte location and size.
4. Using the data form step 3, I then can simply download the manifest file doing by doing another `GET` with the range header equal to `Manifest byte location` + `Manifest size`.
5. That's it. Now I have the manifest.

**Here's my problem**

I can download the last 5kb no problem. What I DON'T know how to do is convert what I've downloaded into hex, so that I may search for the hex signature for the start of the **central directory**.

**What I've attempted**

```
// This is an ArrayBuffer that is what came back from the GET.
var fileResponse = file; 

// Turn it into a Buffer
var myBuffer = new Buffer( new Uint8Array(file) );

// Convert to hex
var hex = myBuffer.toString('hex');

// Search for the hex signature
var centralDirectoryStartIndex = hex.indexOf('02014b50');
```

This is about as far as I got. `centralDirectoryStartIndex` is always `-1`. I'm almost certain that it should contain that hex signature (02014b50)!

What am I missing? Am I converting it into hex incorrectly??

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: can you feed the Buffer constructor an ArrayBuffer? i didn't see that mentioned in the docs...

Comment: The answer, **I think**, is yes. But I wouldn't recommend it as it's not in the docs. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a colleague, I was able to figure this one out. The answer had to do with [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). The long and short of it is that since zip headers need to be read as little-endians, I needed to reverse the bytes in the hex signature before I searched for them.

In a future edit, I'll fill in the full solution. I just wanted to post that I no longer needed assistance so as to save any potential answerers some time.